# Request.IsAjaxRequest() is false when submit is triggered with JavaScript

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a mvc3 Ajax.BeginForm. Instead of clicking on the button I would like to have the button clicked by JavaScript from a onblur event from one of the text boxes.

I've tried the code below and also just calling a function with $('#submitEmail').click(); in it. The submit works and I get a post back but the problem is in the Controller Request.IsAjaxRequest() is false. When I click the button myself Request.IsAjaxRequest() is true.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LeadEmail, new { onBlur = "this.form.submit();" })
```

Yes I've checked with fiddler X-Requested-With is not present when using JavaScript trigger. How can I get it to submit the form on the onBlur event and get the proper ajax header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to add something to Tigran's answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FormAjaxSubmit() {
        var f = $("form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Control/Action",
            type: "POST",
            data: { formCollection: f },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#resultDiv').html(result);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure why the way I was trying doesn't work. The way I see it should work. I press the button or the code presses the button should be the same. Apparently there's a difference. Maybe somebody with knowledge in this area can inform us.
But the solution is to actually do an ajax post.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function FormAjaxSubmit() {
    var someThing = $("#SomeThing").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Control/Action",
        type: "POST",
        data: { SomeThing: someThing },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#resultDiv').html(result);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling submit method on a form is essentially same as clicking on submit button of a form, and when you do that, the browser does a request based on a method type (GET/POST) defined in method attribute.

Calling submit is not an ajax request, it's a form submit that does a full page reload and that is why it didn't work.

Comment: calling this.form.submit() was just one of the things I tried. I also tried calling .click() on the button. So me clicking on the button worked but calling .clikc() of the same button didn't work.